# Eclipse smart quotes - like in Textmate

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, development-environment, pydev

Happy Friday — Does anyone know if eclipse has the notion of smart quotes like Textmate.  The way it works is to select some words and quote them by simply hitting the <kbd>"</kbd> key?  I'm a newbie here so be gentle.  FWIW - I'm using pydev in Eclipse.

Thanks

**Rephrase**

What I am looking for is given I have a word or phrase selected on the screen, I would like to simply hit the '"' key and have the entire word or phrase enclosed by quotes.  The same would apply to various keys — like ([{"'`.

So say I have the following code

```
a = {}
a[keyword] = 1
```

Now (in python) keyword should be in quotes.  I should be able to double click (select) keyword and simply type the <kbd>'</kbd> and then viola the whole word is quoted.  Right now what happens is that keyword is replaced by a single quote...  Sigh..

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible in eclipse. However Eclipse supports automatic quote closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest PyDev, it should work exactly as you want already (tested in PyDev 2.2.3 -- this was actually around for some time already).

Answer (score 2):

For Java and XML files you can create a new template in Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Templates. The template text could look something like this:

```
"${word_selection}${}"${cursor}
```

Then you can apply this template activate code completion using a standard Ctrl-Space (may have to hit it 2 or 3 times to get to the template selector) and then select your quote template.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are asking, is it that...

if you press X-key it will select the current word that the cursor is in?

If that is the question, then I don't think so. 
There are lots of possible keybinding that are not set in eclipse. See Window > Preferences > General > Keys

Update:

Sorry I don't think there is a action to do this in eclipse.
A plugin may exist that you can attach to a key binding, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for — I'll try to rephrase my question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might check out how one of the comment commands work. For example, if I select say 4 lines of code and I want to line comment all of them I can simply select them then hit ctrl+/ and all of the selected lines of code will be commented.

I'm a long time textmate user and I'm missing it something terrible. I forced myself to make a hard switch away from my mac. I'll investigate as time permits but I can't keep getting stuck on minor tweaks at the moment.

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Here is one written in Autohotkey:

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input
#InstallKeybdHook
#UseHook On

(::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("(" sel ")")
        else
            Send (
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        Send (
Return

"::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("""" sel """")
        else
            Send "
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        Send "
Return

'::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("'" sel "'")
        else
            Send '
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        Send '
Return

{::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("{" sel "}")
        else
            Send {{}}
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        SendRaw {
Return

[::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("[" sel "]")
        else
            Send [
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        Send [
Return

<::
    if GetKeyState("ScrollLock","T")
    {
        sel := GetSelection(1)
        if sel
            PasteText("<" sel ">")
        else
            Send <
        sel := ""
    }
    else
        Send <
Return


GetSelection(wait = "")
{
    ClipBack := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := ""
    Send ^c
    if wait
        ClipWait 0.05
    Selection := Clipboard
    Clipboard := ClipBack
    Return Selection
}
```

After installing Autohotkey, save this code to a text file, rename the extension to .ahk and run it. It requires the Scroll Lock to be turned on for the code to work.

This code is modified from http://www.autohotkey.net/~Vifon/ to:

1. Include ' and <
2. Write ', ", <, {, [, ( instead of '', "", <>, {}, [], () when no text is selected.